# Making commits simpler in Git using PowerShell

Tags: git, powershell, windows-10

I'm using Git and being an old dude, I prefer to punch my will on the keyboard rather than send a rodent on a clicky trip. So, usually when I finish off my work, I'll go something like this in the console.

> git add .
>   git commit --message "Cure for cancer (or so it feels like)"
>   git push

I could have a static script doing that but, regrettably, not every day's contribution is as awesome as the cure for cancer, so I'd need to have a script that takes a parameter (and if none is provided, it could be substituted by e.g. "*donkey*".

How would I go about creating such script?

I've googlearched it a bit but got a lot of different suggestions and at my competence level with PowerShell, I have the fear that I'll screw something up really badly. Creating a batch file would be an option but now that I do the magic in PowerShell, I fell I ought to learn it a bit more. As long as we can keep the learning curve not very steep, hehe.

Suggestions?

Comment: create a function that has all the commands you want to execute. the function can have parameters that you can use to perform your logic. just make sure you are in a git shell when executing the function and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Nkosi I will **not** be in a Git shell. I'll be doing that from the plain PowerShell. However, I've configured the system already so that *git* is a known command.

Comment: OK cool. then just create your function. you could go as far as creating a module and have it loaded in your session so you can just call the the cmdlt

Comment: Perfect! Sounds easy enough. Is the suggestion with module anything like the answer below from @sodawillow by any chance?

Comment: Yes. module is just a collection of functions. that answer is basically what I was suggesting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To extend Sergiu Vidrascu's answer, you can wrap the code in a function :

```
function Finish-WorkAndGoHome {
    param([string]$mes = "Curing cancer with every commit")

    git add .
    git commit -m $mes
    git push
}
```

and add it to your profile so that the function is available in every Powershell session you start.

In a PS console, run `notepad $profile`, paste the code in the notepad window and save the file, for instance (then use a new console window to load the new profile).

You can learn more about Powershell profiles [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/). Setting the scripting rights is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Execution_Policies).

Comment: I'm heading out to the movies right now but I'll make sure to try that in the evening. If I forget to accept it by Monday, please kick me to remind.  :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use simple parameters In PowerShell scripts.

Have a magic.ps1 file with something like this:

```
param ( [string]$mes = "Curing cancer with every commit")

git add .
git commit -m $mes
git push
```

When you run it without arguments it picks up the default message.

When you run it like

```
magic.ps1 -mes "did something here"
```

It will use your message.

Comment: And where/how do I save the PS1 file so that it's accessible from anywhere on my system?

Comment: Add it anywhere and append the parent folder path to the PATH environment variable

Comment: Putting a function in the user's [profile](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/) is preferable to needlessly adding folders to the PATH.

Comment: True that, i agree, It is preferable, but since he is fairly new to powershell i wanted to show him something he would maybe relate much easyer.